# in what cases does scala properly convert String to java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, scala, templates, generics

Say that I make a single parameter generic method:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  def method():T
}
```

And then extend it and parametrize. This:

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait[java.lang.String] {
  def method() = "foo"
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait[String] {
  def method() = "foo"
}
```

However, when you make a trait-method that parametrizes a lambda like so:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def apply[T](input:()=>T):T
}
```

Then you're not so lucky. This:

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  def apply(input:()=>java.lang.String) = "foo"
}
```

Will lead to this:

```
Error:(25, 45) type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("foo")
 required: String
      def apply[String](input:()=>String) = "foo"
                                    ^
```

Yet, this is fine:

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  def apply[String](input:()=>String) = new String("foo")
}
```

So in what cases does scalac actually know the conversion needs to be done and in what cases does it not?

Furthermore, even if I write out the entire path to the java.lang.String type

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  def apply[java.lang.String](input:()=>java.lang.String) = new java.lang.String("foo")
}
```

It throws another error:

```
Error:(25, 21) ']' expected but '.' found.
      def apply[java.lang.String](input:()=>java.lang.String) = new java.lang.String("foo")
                    ^
```

If I wanted to actually do it this latter way by templating java.lang.String directly, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: `def apply[String]` You are declaring a type parameter named `String` here.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  def apply[String](input:()=>String) = new String("foo")
}
```

isn't fine. It results in `class type required but String found`. The problem here is that you don't declare what a type parameter is when you extend a class with a parameterized method. You declare it when you USE the method.

Let's rewrite that:

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  def apply[String](input:()=>String) = input()
}
```

Now observe:

```
scala> (new MyClass).apply[String](() => "foo")
res0: String = foo

scala> (new MyClass).apply[Int](() => 5)
res1: Int = 5
```

It works because when you declared this:

```
  def apply[String](input:()=>String) = input()
```

`String` is *the name of the parameter*. If you wrote `T`, `Xyzzy`, or `ManISuckAtTypeParameters` instead of `String` above it would be THE EXACT SAME THING. You are saying you'll get a type parameter, you'll *name* the type parameter `String`, and that's the value of the return function and, by override, of the `apply` method.

When I call `apply[Int](() => 5)`, Scala will *replace* `String` in the definition with `Int`.

Comment: Whoops, that was really dumb of me. Thanks for the great reply.